# Highlighting the word in arabic in textview

Tags: android, search, arabic-support

i want highlight a Arabic text in `TextView`. that user search in `SearchBar`.
but for example user only search 'فاطمه الزهرا' while in `TextView` is 'فاطِمَهَ الزَّهْراَّء'.
i don't have any problem for search, i have problem for highlight Arabic text with nun nation

```
    private void startSrch (String textToSrch) {
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(desc.getText().toString());
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(textToSrch);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    int cnt =0;
    while (m.find()) {
        cnt++;
        int start = m.start();
        int end = m.end();
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    desc.setText(s);
    Toast.makeText(this,cnt+" نتیجه یافت شد.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    HideKeyboard();

}
```

Comment: does it highlight non-arabic text correctly? how do you highlight it? How us!

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: does it iterate through your loop? does it find any matches?